# Upgrade to Precise messed up GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, 12.04, boot-failure

I just upgraded from Oneiric to Precise and it messed up my GRUB2, now I can't boot and keep getting an **"error: no such partition"** error. This is not the first time this happens but now I can't seem to boot from usb ([separate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122680/cant-boot-from-usb-after-installing-ubuntu)) to repair GRUB2 and I can't find my way in the Rescue Console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use few ways to restore your grub.
Most simple way is loading your **Ubuntu Live CD** with
`no acpi` `no apic` `no lapic` `no raid` `no modeset` options
( F6 on boot screen and select all for exclusion *Free Software Only* ),
choose **Try Ubuntu**, and:

- Tune Network connection and connect Internet.
- Run terminal.
- Run:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```

In your *Guest session* will be installed *Boot Repair* program.

How to use it and more information about restoring boot you can read here:
[Ubuntu Documentation > Community Documentation > Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

More complicated way:
[Grub Rescue commands](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html)

Comment: Why boot with the `no acpi` `no apic` `no lapic` `no raid` `no modeset` options? Why not just boot the **Ubunut Live CD** and run `boot-repair`?

Comment: despite the fact that no necessary options, disabling ACPI and EDD (Enhanced Disk Drive) can avoid occurs some errors with mounting guest session + installing boot-repair ... so disabling signed set will create maximally virtual session and avoiding unneeded dependencies. though, sure, it's only my own experience.

Comment: `acpi=off` must be used with caution. Use it as last resort, it can cause to overheat and permanent damage to system. More info -> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: it's actual for running of **full installed system**. _Guest session_ is limited for resource consumption and it's appropriate for rapid Live Ubuntu repair session.

Comment: settings on boot screen of Live CD not related to Grub installed on HDD partition ... It's options for booting from CD.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to restore grub (what should fix your problem) is to burn a [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/), then boot from it, choose to scan for operationg systems, start Ubuntu, log in and execute the command `sudo update-grub`.

EDIT: If that doesn't work, do the same again but this time execute `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`. sdX has to be replaced with the real harddrives dev-name. Do not do this unless you are sure you are doing it for the right harddrive!